# Does Apache HTTP WebServer require JDK/JRE?

Tags: java, apache, java-8, webserver, weblogic

I want to use the Apache HTTP WebServer just for accessing the enterprise application which is on WebLogic both Apache & WebLogic will be on different servers. So my question here is Does Apache HTTP WebServer requires JDK/JRE?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, Apache Http Server does not require JDK/JRE.